# How Can I import or open a .dmp file?

Tags: oracle, impdp, imp, oracle-dump

Update:

[I tried the impdp command and it's giving me that it cannot create a user. I tried creating the user as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6DoQ.png)

[This is how my .par file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdbem.png)

[This is a snip of .sh file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0GbE.png)

[image]

I have never used the oracle database before. I have a .dmp file which is 50 GB. I don't know how it was exported or which version it was exported from. I downloaded Oracle 12c release 2 and tried to do an import but I get the error ".dmp may be a Data Pump export dump file". What do I need to do so that I can run SQL queries on it eventually? Please see the attached image.

UPDATE :
I tried the command :
IMP SYSTEM/Password SHOW=Y FILE=DBO_V7WRIGLEY_PROD_20180201_TECHOPS-5527.dmp fromuser=SYSTEM touser=SYSTEM

It gave me a message saying import terminated successfully with warnings. what does this do? Also, where can I view the data now if it's imported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in **sqlplus** as **SYSTEM**:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY IMPDIR as 'C:\Users\negink\Documents\databasewrigley';
```

back in command line:

```
impdp SYSTEM/Password DUMPFILE=IMPDIR:DBO_V7WRIGLEY_PROD_20180201_TECHOPS-5527.dmp logfile=IMPDIR:DBO_V7WRIGLEY_PROD_20180201_TECHOPS-5527.log FULL=Y
```

when done, you can remove the DIRECTORY object

> in a CDB database (which is your case), this will not work, unless you
>   pre-create all the users and roles in SQLPLUS, after running this command:

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
create user x identified by pwdx;
create user y identified by pwdy;
create role r1;
create role r2;
...
```

Otherwize, you can create a PDB inside your CDB and import your DMP file into the PDB. In this case, you'll need to modify the connection in the IMPDP command as follows (change **SYSTEM/Password** to **SYSTEM/Password@//localhost/pdb_name**) :

```
impdp SYSTEM/Password@//localhost/pdb_name DUMPFILE=IMPDIR:DBO_V7WRIGLEY_PROD_20180201_TECHOPS-5527.dmp logfile=IMPDIR:DBO_V7WRIGLEY_PROD_20180201_TECHOPS-5527.log FULL=Y
```

Comment: it gave me the following message : Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed with 1149 error(s) at Thu Feb 15 16:11:52 2018 elapsed 0 00:00:14 . Where can I look for all the files now ?

Comment: What does it say in the logfile?

Comment: It says : Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  SYSTEM/******** DUMPFILE=IMPDIR:DBO_V7WRIGLEY_PROD_20180201_TECHOPS-5527.dmp logfile=IMPDIR:DBO_V7WRIGLEY_PROD_20180201_TECHOPS-5527.log FULL=Y 
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
ORA-39083: Object type USER:"DBO_V7WRIGLEY_PROD" failed to create with error:
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name

Comment: Is it similar to this? https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9522287800346730171

Comment: #!/bin/bash

SCHEMA=${PWD##*/}
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)

COMMENT=comment

EXPDPKEYS="\
       DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR \
       SCHEMAS=$SCHEMA \
       DUMPFILE=$SCHEMA"_"$DATE"_"$COMMENT.DMP \
       LOGFILE=$SCHEMA"_"$DATE"_"$COMMENT.LOG"


expdp user/pass@server:port/SID $EXPDPKEYS
 This command was used for export

Comment: It seems you're importing into a CDB database which requires users to have the C## prefix.
There is a workaround but it only works in SQLPLUS session:
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
For your case (using IMPDP), you either need to import this dmp file into a PDB, or create a LOGON trigger to automatically run the ALTER SESSION statement for any new session...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should use **impdp** instead of **imp**. And don't forget to take backups before doing anything. Also, you should have your dmp file on your server's local directory. I've seen people trying to import dmp files located on their computer's hard drive. That's not how things work.

I recommend you to drop the schema if you are importing to an existing schema for better results.

To drop an existing schema, login to sqlplus with an admin account

> sqlplus username/password@connect_identifier

Then you can use this command to drop the schema:

```
DROP USER <SCHEMA_NAME> CASCADE;
```

Query your DB to see if data pump directory is defined

```
SELECT directory_name, directory_path FROM dba_directories WHERE directory_name='DATA_PUMP_DIR'
```

If directory is not defined use this command to define (btw "D:\orcl12" is my oracle instance path, you should use your own path)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DATA_PUMP_DIR AS 'D:\orcl12c/admin/<ORA_INSTANCE_NAME>/dpdump/';
```

Quit sqlplus to command prompt and run impdp with admin credentials (Be sure there's no other logfile with the same name on source directory - if so operation will abort)

> impdp username/password@connect_identifier directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=filename.dmp logfile=filename.log

If the operation succeeds you may have to update User-Defined Datatypes manually because they are not importing correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the update . I will try this but I have the .dmp file on my computer locally. Its not on any server

Comment: It should be on the same machine with the server. If server is installed on your computer then it's ok.

Comment: sorry but I got a bit confused. Which server do you refer to ?I am doing everything locally here on my desktop

Comment: Is your Oracle DB installed on your local computer or on a remote computer? Your .dmp file must be on the same computer where your Oracle DB is installed.

Comment: its on a local computer where db is installed

Comment: did you see my update ? I posed a snip of my .sh and .par file . Do I need to change anything based on that ? I tried this   sqlplus username/password@connect_identifier  and this gave me an error ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.Also I am using system user. Is that okay ?

Comment: #!/bin/bash

SCHEMA=${PWD##*/}
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)

COMMENT=comment

EXPDPKEYS="\
       DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR \
       SCHEMAS=$SCHEMA \
       DUMPFILE=$SCHEMA"_"$DATE"_"$COMMENT.DMP \
       LOGFILE=$SCHEMA"_"$DATE"_"$COMMENT.LOG"


expdp user/pass@server:port/SID $EXPDPKEYS
this command was used for export